# sum up values of compressed time series over time

Tags: r

I try to describe my problem via the code below. I have a data frame of a 'compressed' time series in the form of data frame: have. It contains the start and end date of a period with a value over time. I want to repeat the data as in data frame: want to ultimately get to the data frame: ultimately_want which sums up the value over time. Maybe I do not need want and get straight to ultimately_want somehow? Thanks.

```
library(dplyr)

start_date <- as.Date(c("2004-08-02", "2004-08-03"))
end_date <- as.Date(c("2004-08-04", "2004-08-05"))
value <- c(5, 6)
have <- data.frame(start_date, end_date, value)
have

date <- as.Date(c("2004-08-02", "2004-08-03", "2004-08-04", "2004-08-03", "2004-08-04", "2004-08-05"))
value <- c(5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
want <- data.frame(date, value)
want

ultimately_want <- want %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(value))

ultimately_want
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(have)[, .(value = value, date = seq(start_date, end_date, by = "day")), 
                                     by = 1:nrow(have)][,.(total = sum(value)), date][]

#         date total
#1: 2004-08-02     5
#2: 2004-08-03    11
#3: 2004-08-04    11
#4: 2004-08-05     6
```